# What is the value for white in this png filter?

Tags: c++, image-processing, libpng

I have this short code in C++ : `png_set_filler(png, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);`
This colored the transparent pixels in black.
I think that `0xFF` means black. What is the value for white ?
Thanks

Comment: If 0xFF is black then 0x00 is probably white.

Comment: @drescherjm Why not 0xFFFFFFFF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function takes packed (alpha-less RGB) values and adds an alpha channel.

```cpp
png_set_filler(png_ptr, filler, PNG_FILLER_BEFORE);
```

The `filler` is the value to put in the unpacked alpha channel. The final param is either `PNG_FILLER_BEFORE` or `PNG_FILLER_AFTER`, which places the filled channel before or after the RGB values -- ARGB or RGBA, respectively.

[The docs](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html) say, "To add an opaque alpha channel, use filler=0xff [or 0xffff for 16-bit color channels]", which I believe means no transparency so it will show up as whatever the RGB values are (in your case, that is presumably all zeros). Note that, as I read the docs, using this function on an already unpacked PNG has no effect -- i.e., it doesn't to modify the fill value.

If your RGB values were, say, `0xff0000`, that would be solid red. If unpacked red pixels and set the fill channel to `0x7f`, that should make it half-transparent red.